# Angular JS, bind scope property to function

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I'm new to Angular JS. I am creating an app that stores data in the web storage. WHen an enquiry form is submitted, it gets the current arrays from the web storage, strigifies the new form data, adds it to an array, and posts it back to web storage. Works great and all gets saved correctly.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
   // get object from form data
    var formData = { firstName: $scope.firstName, lastName: $scope.lastName, date: getDateFromatted(), posted: false };
    addStoredData(formData, ENQUIRY_STORE);
}

function getStoredData(storeName) {
    // get or create enquiry store
    var storedData = (typeof localStorage.getItem(storeName) !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem(storeName)) || "[]";

    // parse store into object
    storedData = JSON.parse(storedData);

    return storedData;
}

function addStoredData(data, storeName) {
     var storedData = getStoredData(storeName);
     var count = storedData.length;

     // form data into next submission slot
     storedData[count] = data;

     // turn back into JSON
     storedData = JSON.stringify(storedData);

     // slap it back in web storage
     localStorage.setItem(storeName, storedData);
}
```

On my HTML page I have this;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="e in enquiries">
        <td>{{ e.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.lastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.date }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I want to be able to do this...

```
// list of stored enquiries
$scope.enquiries = function () {
    return getStoredData(ENQUIRY_STORE);
}
```

But it doesn't bind and there are no rows. If I do this...

```
$scope.enquiries = getStoredData(ENQUIRY_STORE);
```

it works, but then I have to keep setting it when a new enquiry is submitted. Maybe Anulgar doesn't let you have use functions to return data for binding, but I thought it did.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks logic to me. Currently you're not triggering $scope.enquiries when it's a function.

Comment: You should begin by storing your data list into a $scope object, and make sure your "add" and "delete" function not only impact localStorage, but the $scope object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first way (`$scope.enquiries = function() ...`) it doesn't bind because you are making an ngRepeat over a function (it doesn't throw an error because a function has actually a length).

However, even if you did `<tr ng-repeat="e in enquiries()">` you would have a infinite digest error because enquiries() is returning a different object each time and angular is waiting to have the same result twice to stop the digests cycle.

The best way would be:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  ...
  setEnquiries();
}

...

function setEnquiries() {
  $scope.enquiries = getStoredData(ENQUIRY_STORE);
}
```

And keep looping through enquiries:

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in enquiries">
```

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explanation - works well now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.selectedENQUIRY_STORE = null;
$scope.getStoredData= function (e) {
    $scope.selectedENQUIRY_STORE = e;
};
```

it binds when you clicked on that enquiry form on name

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to retrieve the data again, upon submitting, so move your **$scope.enquiries()** function into your **$scope.submit()** function.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
   // get object from form data
    var formData = { firstName: $scope.firstName, lastName: $scope.lastName, date: getDateFromatted(), posted: false };
    addStoredData(formData, ENQUIRY_STORE);

// FIRE UP THE FUNCTION
$scope.enquiries();
}
```

Note that you should put getStoredData() and other data related function into an angular service.

Luckily, there's already a good module for dealing with LocalStorage operations : 
https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker